# How to assign argument of type promise

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to work on some unit test with jest to test, I have two function in separate file called generator in which I create fake data :

**generator.ts**

```
export async function generateReportData(overide = {}) {
    return {
        clientId: faker.datatype.number(),
        incidentDesc: faker.lorem.sentence(15),
        city: faker.address.city(),
        country: faker.address.country(),
        createdAt: new Date(),
        ...overide,
    };
}

export async function generateReportsData(n: number = 1, overide = {}) {
    return Array.from(
        {
            length: n,
        },
        (_, i) => {
            return generateReportData({ id: i, ...overide });
        }
    );
}
```

when I try to create unit test with jest like that :

```
 test("should return report list", async () => {
            const reportsData = generateReportsData(4);
            const spy = jest
                .spyOn(ReportRepository, "getReports")
                .mockResolvedValueOnce(reportsData);
            const controller = new ReportController();
            const reports = await controller.getReports();
            expect(reports).toEqual(reportsData);
            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        });
```

I got this error :

> Argument of type 'Promise<{ clientId: number; incidentDesc: string;
> city: string; country: string; createdAt: Date; }>[]' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'Report[] | Promise<Report[]>'.

Here is my repository :

```
import { getRepository } from "typeorm";
import { Report } from "../models";

export interface IReportPayload {
    incidentDesc: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
}

export const getReports = async (): Promise<Array<Report>> => {
    const reportRepository = getRepository(Report);
    return reportRepository.find();
};
```

Comment: Where does `ReportController` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you did not type the return value from the `generateReportData` function, so typescript doesn't know that the type is actually `Report` (also, why is it async?). Just add the type and you should be fine:

```
export function generateReportData(overide = {}): Report
```